# Java Equivalent of Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, java, porting, reflection.emit

As far as I can tell, Java has no such equivalent of C#'s `Reflection.Emit` stuff. Are there any additional libraries for Java that provide similar functionality? What are the differences (to *reflection emit*)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides Darin's excellent answer (+1), [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) is worth checking out too.

Comment: After investigating it seems ASM is the best fit for me. I also came across some stuff that compared it favourably with regard to performance. Thanks!

Comment: @PythonPower: since you've investigated ASM, can you tell me if it allow the emitted bytecode to be run at runtime? And/or if BCEL does if you've found out since?

Answer (score 11):

[The Byte Code Engineering Library (BCEL)](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/)

Comment: Does BCEL allow the emitted bytecode to be run at runtime (as opposed to saving it to a file)?

Comment: Can someone please answer this question?

Comment: @JaySullivan Given the age of this you may already know this: you are more likely to get responses on new questions than hoping someone answers a comment on an old question.

Comment: @vossad01 as far as I know SO, the new question gets closed within few minutes for being a duplicate :-\