# How to create Java classes Dynamically by Java Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic

Reflection is used to load java class classes and manipulate them on the fly. But I have across a weird question that is asking me how to create Java classes on the fly by Reflection.I mean the classes is not compiled or have source code till we want them created. Is it really possible? Any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ASM 
[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)

or Byte code engineering library

[Byte code engineering library](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/)

for manipulating, creating classes at run time

In .NET we have Reflection.Emit(C#) which can do that
[Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kyyyeh2.aspx)

Not sure whether there is a direct java equivalent.
You can see another similar question on SO here [Java equivalent of reflection.emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259323/java-equivalent-of-reflection-emit)

Comment: byte code manipulation is neede. Actually Javassist library is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look look at [Bean Shell's eval method](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/embeddedmode.html#eval%28%29) It lets you execute any Java code on the fly without the need to compile the code into bytecode. You can pass a string containing all the Java code for your class to it's eval method and you'll get back an instance of the dynamically created class. Let me know if you're interested in it and want me to give you an example.

Comment: but the the class denoted by `className` is not compiled, there is no trace of it in the byte code nor source code. `forName()` will fail, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you don't need reflection, but just need to call the JavaCompiler directly from your code: [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Apache [DynaBeans](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean.html) will do. You can find some tutorials on creating and manipulating them eg. here: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/07/TouringTheCommonsPart1.html