# Running a user created Java class

Tags: java, class, instantiation

In my main program I am allowing users to create Java classes and storing them in a `.java` file within the package `UserInputs`. I am now looking for a way to instantiate the user created class within my main program and also running the public methods within the class.

Here is the code which gets executed when the user presses a `JButton` to finish creating their class.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == inputButt.getButtons()){
        try{

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/human/Desktop/UserInputTest/src/UserInputs/UserCreatedClass.java", "UTF-8");
            writer.println(textArea.getText());
            writer.close();

        }catch(Exception except){
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can compile a java file during runtime like you're proposing

Comment: See [compiling and running user code with JavaCompiler and ClassLoader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158429/compiling-and-running-user-code-with-javacompiler-and-classloader).

Comment: interesting question but i dont think this is possible. when you run the main program, UserCreatedClass.java has not been compiled, so how could it be instantiated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Java classes Dynamically by Java Reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125583/how-to-create-java-classes-dynamically-by-java-reflection)

Comment: @OlivierH I don't think that this is a duplicate of this post, since he wants to compile and execute a dynamically created java file and don't want to create one via byte code manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the file at runtime. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064259/how-can-i-compile-and-deploy-a-java-class-at-runtime) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051884/generating-compiling-and-using-java-code-at-run-time) post here on SO helps you.

What the first link says is that you should use the Java 6 Compiler API. What you need to do is this:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
```

Where `fileToCompile` is the path to your file, in your case "C:/Users/human/Desktop/UserInputTest/src/UserInputs/UserCreatedClass.java". Then you can execute the code via Reflection.

I would be very carefully with letting people create and execute their own Java code, though. I don't know what you plan to do but if you are running this code on a server, I would not recommend doing such things. In case this application should run locally on the clients computer (so they can only harm themselves) this should not be a problem. Otherwise I would not let them program what they want.

Comment: So I did what you suggested and used this website to help me invoke the methods: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider Groovy compiler which is almost fully compatible with Java syntax, more functional and has simpler API. [Example from a Groovy page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy):

> ```
> ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
> GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
> Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(new File("src/test/groovy/script/HelloWorld.groovy"));
>
> // let's call some method on an instance
> GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
> Object[] args = {};
> groovyObject.invokeMethod("run", args);
> ```